# Is Home Activity instantiated multiple times?

Tags: android

The official [Dev Guide of Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) says, activities can be instantiated multiple times, and Home Activity is taken as an example

[image: a single activity is instantiated multiple times]

So I tried it out as the graph illustrates:

1. Launch Activity 2
2. Press Home button
3. Launch Activity 1
4. Press Back button (so I return to Home screen)
5. Press Back button again

But I did not go back to Activity 1. Thus, it seems that Home Activity has not been instantiated multiple times. Is it so? If so, how is it kept in a Back Stack?

EDIT: Sorry, I should've clarified earlier that I didn't write any codes to test it. All I've done is just launching applications on favorites tray. I'd better go to read the source code and search for the behavior of Home Activity.
Anyway, I don't think Home Activity is a good example here to illustrate multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be that you might have called `finish()` in your `Activity2`. Or, the OS clears up the 2nd `Activity` before you return back to it. The behavior you are trying to attain on your own has no guarantees. You can't force an `Activity` to keep running so that you can return back to it.